# How to click button automatically when redirect from another page in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two files, which is index.html and myfile.html,in index.html there is a link to redirect another page like Download and in myfile.html file, there is a button like

```
<button onClick="$('.table').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});" class="btn btn-default btn-xs pull-right"><i>Excel</i></button>
```

If user click this button from myfile.html, excel file will be download.So its two steps right?
What I want to do is like when user click a link from index.html, I want to download directly, like opening another page and downloading the file.
Is there anyway to do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a selector to the download button and trigger the click event when user redirect to the `myfile.html`. Like :

On load of the `myfile.html`, put this script on that

```
$("download_button_selector").trigger("click");
```

Comment: is there any function to wait 5 sec to trigger the click event ? because its too fast, my data is loading at that time like 3 sec needed to be fully show. Thanks bro anyway

Comment: Yeah, you can use `setInterval` for prevent the action for a certain time period